# HttpWebResponse dealing with login delay

Tags: c#, webrequest, httpwebresponse

I am trying to read a page from a website that logs me in automatically. The problem is the site when launched first gives a page saying "Logging you in" with a loading icon. That happens for about 5 seconds or so and than the actual page loads.

When I run my code it only gets the logon page with icon code and not the actual page after the logon.

Anyway I can get both?

Thanks

```
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://server1/test");
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You have to replicate what a browser does - how does the browser go from the icon page to the login page? Is there a redirect, or automatic form submission?  You should inspect the browser view source to see.

Comment: The http should terminate with a status.  Usually it is 200 done when complete.  Sometimes you will get a 100 Continue which means you have to send another request to get rest of message.  Http has version 1.o which is stream mode and 1.1 which is chunk.  If the server is returning 1.1 you have to switch to 1.0.  Use following :  HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://server1/test");
            request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;

Comment: it appears the page has more than one <html> space filtered by class, so it is enabling and disabling the <html> markup after the loading page.

Anyway I can get the code after it enabled the new class?